# Building Unity on Android produces the error 'CommandInvokationFailure'.

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have installed the latest unity 3D version(5.5.1) and the latest Android SDK. I haven't built my project on Android before - I believe I get an error when it tries to generate an Android Manifest XML:

Some suggestions for this error for old versions of Android wanted the `build-tools` folder of a particular version deleted but this still doesn't work. Could somebody help me out here?

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Users\price\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/price/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.onesignal:com.onesignal.onesignalsdk:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.gcm:com.google.android.gms.location:android.support.v4 -S "C:\Users\price\OneDrive\Documents\FantasyMatchday_iOS\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\onesignal-unity\res" -S "C:\Users\price\OneDrive\Documents\FantasyMatchday_iOS\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\OneSignalConfig\res" -S "C:\Users\price\OneDrive\Documents\FantasyMatchday_iOS\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-8.3.0\res" -S "C:\Users\price\OneDrive\Documents\FantasyMatchday_iOS\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-8.3.0\res" -S "C:\Users\price\OneDrive\Documents\FantasyMatchday_iOS\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gcm-8.3.0\res" -S "C:\Users\price\OneDrive\Documents\FantasyMatchday_iOS\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-location-8.3.0\res" -S "C:\Users\price\OneDrive\Documents\FantasyMatchday_iOS\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.1.0\res"

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:20: Tag <category> attribute name has invalid character '$'.
AndroidManifest.xml:51: Tag <permission> attribute name has invalid character '$'.
AndroidManifest.xml:52: Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character '$'.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
(default)

Files:
AndroidManifest.xml
Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package: C:\Users\price\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=powered_by_google_dark.png
...
...
```

Comment: can you show us your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I don't think there is one, I think it tries to generate an apk but fails when generating a manifest.xml and therefore the whole export fails

Comment: If you create a new project with just an empty scene, can you build that on android?

Comment: Hmm, yes a blank project builds fine. What could be wrong with mine? :(

Comment: What native plugins are you using?

Comment: I'm using Photon, OneSignal, Facebook API.. that's about it really. Do you think of those could be causing the issue?

Comment: Remove one plugin after another, until it compiles properly. The you know where the wrong manifest.xml comes from.